# Bot stopped responding, no errors logged

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hangouts

I had a bot working. It pulled data based on a keyword search from a spreadsheet. It suddenly stopped working - with *no* changes to the code - and is not logging any events in `onMessage`, `onAddToSpace` or `onRemoveFromSpace`.

Sending a DM to the bot responds with "Bot not responding". I have check the Cloud Console and it is published to my account with the correct ID. All fields in the console match settings in the bot headers. Nothing is logged to StackDriver.

I also had a webapp deployed with the bot, and it was working concurrently. I disabled the web app to no results.

The most confounding issue is that *other* bots deployed are still working. What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

I went through all of the API scopes I needed. I was pulling from `DriveApp` and the YouTube data API. Disabling the YouTube API has allowed the app to start working again.

**UPDATE 2**

Porting the code to a separate working bot allowed the YouTube API to begin working again. The other project was also serving a web app, but disabling the app didn't make any change. I think there is some kind of permissions conflict when a single script is serving multiple resources. Perhaps the chat bot uses a hidden URL that is in conflict with a hosted web app. I cannot find any documentation about how the chatbot is served from apps script other than the deployment ID. Is there another piece to the puzzle?

Comment: What's your resource quota usage looking like?

Comment: Way below. Quota for the YouTube API is 1M/day, 300K/100s/user, 3M/100sec. I'm the only one using it right now.

Comment: Very strange indeed. Running the functions manually in the script editor doesn't reveal any errors?

Comment: It could be that the link between Hangouts Chat and Apps Script got broken. I'd try toggling the Hangouts Chat API config to an HTTP endpoint, save, and then toggle back to your script's deployment ID.

Comment: @EricKoleda I can't test scripts from the editor because it's the `onMessage` event that's causing the breakdown. I toggled to HTTPS and back, no luck there. I might set up a new project and duplicate the code as a last resort.

Comment: [Posted a bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:350158%2B%20status:open%20type:bug%20&p=1)